# Unable to download a image from S3 Bucket written in Node.Js using AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Below is the total code to download an image from the s3 written in Node.Js and execution on AWS Lambda. But, it got stuck on the line s3.getObject({ Bucket, Key, ResponseContentType: 'text/plain' }).promise().
I've tried it multiple ways but nothing worked out. I'm out of the ideas now. . It would be a great help if you guys tell me where I did wrong.

```
        const path = require('path')
        const fs = require('fs')
        const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

        AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx'
        })

        const outputFilePath = path.resolve('/tmp/imotmp', path.parse('Tobacco-Halifax-Oak-worktops.jpg').base)
        const { Key, Bucket } = data

        const s3 = new AWS.S3({})
        console.log('downloading...')
        let s3Data = await s3.getObject({ Bucket, Key, ResponseContentType: 'text/plain' }).promise()

        fs.writeFile(outputFilePath, s3Data.Body, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('writeFile', error)
            }
            console.log('completed', outputFilePath)
            return { message: 'hurray' }
        })
```

Comment: Please add the errors/logs to the question. That helps us understand the problem better.

Comment: It got stuck at the line   s3.getObject   it is not throwing any error or any logs.

Comment: Is your Lambda function configured to run in a VPC?

Comment: S3 getObject just needs a bucket and a key and the image binary data is returned so you don't need to access with s3Data.body. Also, I'd check that your lambda function has the required IAM role to access S3.

Comment: I've given "s3:*", total access

Comment: I figured it out the problem, I run in a VPC that is configured to run with a MongoDB Atlas when I run without a VPC it worked.